# how to use the variable which define before to set default value in python data class

Tags: python, nameerror, python-dataclasses

I use decoration data class to initial variable but write the following code

```
    class LRUCache(object):
        capacity: int
        map: dict = field(repr=False, default_factory=dict)
        list: DoubleLinkedList = field(repr=False, default=DoubleLinkedList(capacity))

        def print(self):
        self.list.print()
```

and when I running this code I get a error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/boker/code/PyhonCode/ComputerFoundation/computer_principle/cache/LRUCache.py", line 7, in <module>
    class LRUCache(object):
  File "/Users/boker/code/PyhonCode/ComputerFoundation/computer_principle/cache/LRUCache.py", line 10, in LRUCache
    list: DoubleLinkedList = field(repr=False, default=DoubleLinkedList(capacity))
NameError: name 'capacity' is not defined
```

I have tried to find the solution in official document but I failed.How to settle this problem. I use python3.8.4.

Answer (score 0):

As the error says (the value of) `capacity` isn't defined. If you want to set it to a default value just set it to whatever your default value is (e.g. `capacity: int = 10`)

Comment: Here comes mew questions, if I set capacity with default value 10 like `capacity : int = 10` when I new object LRUCache like `cache = LRUCache(2)` the list will set as 10. but my intention is to set dynamically